# ¿Como hacer para agregar un acceso directo de una web a la pantalla de inicio automaticamente?

Tags: php, android, html, css

Disculpen el español, quiero hacer que un boton en mi web le de la orden al navegador de android, que cree un acceso directo de la pagina WEB, pero que lo haga automaticamente que el usuario no tenga que hacer nada mas sino, pulsar el boton ¿alguna idea?

Comment: te sugiero agregar más detalles, una imagen de lo que deseas etc...

Comment: Si todas estas operaciones, crear el boton, dar click y generar un link, son en la página que esta dentro del WebView se puede realizar atraves de una interfaz JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible hacer lo que queres. Lo que se estila es hacer una pagina con las intrucciones para que el usuario lo haga desde las opciones del navegador.